# TemplateDoesNotExist at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I don't know why I am getting this error. Below is the code I am using.

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "mysite", "static", "templates"),)
```

**urls.py**

````
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from notes import views as notes_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', notes_views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]```


**views.py**


`def home(request):
    notes = Note.objects
    template = loader.get_template('note.html')
    context = {'notes': notes}
    return render(request, 'templates/note.html', context)`

NOTE : I am following this tutorial -  https://pythonspot.com/django-tutorial-building-a-note-taking-app/
````

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Django do you use? The tutorial looks outdated.

First set DEBUG = True in your settings.py - it will show you more information.

Comment: it's already DEBUG=TRUE in settings.py. I agree that tutorial is outdated. Can you guess why this is happening. I am using django 2.0.7 version

Comment: Asking questions should in general be done in the comments, not as an answer

Comment: Standard path for templates is myapp/templates/myapp/ and you refer it 'myapp/note.html'.
Then you don't need your setting for TEMPLATE_DIRS.

Answer (score 0):

```
return render(request, 'templates/note.html', context)
```

Try removing templates/ from the line above so you only have the template 'note.html' in the line:

```
return render(request, 'note.html', context)
```